# javascript - concat two arrays but with identical objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this array of all users:

```
let allUsers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Mike"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Kim"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Mike"
    }
];
```

Now I have array of batches.
Each batch has its own users array.

```
const userBatches = [
    {   
        "batchId": 1,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 5,
                name: "Max"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Simon"
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "batchId": 2,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 6,
                name: "Max"
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "Conor"
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "batchId": 3,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Norman"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here I want to push only those users that does not exists in allUsers array. (on the basis of user id not name)

In simple words allUsers should contain the unique users. No duplicates.

Expected response of allUsers:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Mike"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Kim"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Mike"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Max"
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Max"
    },
    {
        id: 7
        name: "Conor"
    }
]
```

Here is the attached code snippet:

```js
let allUsers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Mike"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Kim"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Mike"
    }
];

const userBatches = [
    {   
        "batchId": 1,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 5,
                name: "Max"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Simon"
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "batchId": 2,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 6,
                name: "Max"
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                name: "Conor"
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "batchId": 3,
        "users": [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Norman"
            }
        ]
    }
];

userBatches.forEach((batch) => {
    
  console.log(batch)
    // if batch users does not exists allUsers array then add these users to allUsers array 
});
```

Comment: You pretty much have solved it yourself with your comment after the .log. JS array `some` and you got it.

Comment: yeah I know the concept but I am unable to apply the better approach here, I need a clean and optimized way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s one possible solution using the array method filter:

```
const uniqueUsers = userBatches.flatMap(batch => batch.users)
  .filter(user => !allUsers.some(u => u.id === user.id))
  .concat(allUsers);

console.log(uniqueUsers);

// Output: [
// { id: 1, name: 'Mike' },
// { id: 2, name: 'John' },
// { id: 3, name: 'Kim' },
// { id: 4, name: 'Mike' },
// { id: 5, name: 'Max' },
// { id: 6, name: 'Max' },
// { id: 7, name: 'Conor' }
// ]
```

Comment: Neat solution! I liked this approach as it's readable and clear

Answer (score 0):

```js
let allUsers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kim"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mike"
  }
];

const userBatches = [{
    "batchId": 1,
    "users": [{
        id: 5,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Simon"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 2,
    "users": [{
        id: 6,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: "Conor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 3,
    "users": [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Norman"
    }]
  }
];

userBatches.forEach(ub => {
  ub.users.forEach(ubu => {
    if (!allUsers.some(au => au.id === ubu.id)) allUsers.push(ubu)
  })
})

console.log(allUsers);
```

Comment: Can we avoid ub.users.forEach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if the array has the object by comparing the IDs, as follows:

```js
let allUsers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kim"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mike"
  }
];

const userBatches = [{
    "batchId": 1,
    "users": [{
        id: 5,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Simon"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 2,
    "users": [{
        id: 6,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: "Conor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 3,
    "users": [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Norman"
    }]
  }
];

userBatches.forEach((batch) => {
  batch.users.forEach(user => {
    if (!allUsers.some(u => u.id === user.id)) {
      allUsers.push(user)
    }
  })
});

console.log(allUsers)
```

---

Option 2:

If you want to avoid nested `Array.forEach()`, you can use `Array.filter()` and the spread operator. But note that this way you are creating a new array in each iteration

```js
let allUsers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Kim"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mike"
  }
];

const userBatches = [{
    "batchId": 1,
    "users": [{
        id: 5,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Simon"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 2,
    "users": [{
        id: 6,
        name: "Max"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: "Conor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "batchId": 3,
    "users": [{
      id: 3,
      name: "Norman"
    }]
  }
];

userBatches.forEach((batch) => {
  allUsers = [...allUsers, ...batch.users.filter(user => !allUsers.some(u => u.id === user.id))]
});

console.log(allUsers)
```

Comment: any way to avoid batch.users.forEach?

Comment: @StormTrooper I added the 2nd option per your request

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution would be to create a map `id=>user` and populate it from both arrays:

```
uniqueUsers = [...new Map([
    ...allUsers.map(u => [u.id, u]),
    ...userBatches.flatMap(b => b.users).map(u => [u.id, u])
]).values()];
```

Comment: This is better but I would like foreach to stay as is, since i need to perform insertion to db in foreach